# Create a variable Date in format "yyyy-mm-dd"

Tags: java, sqlite, date, jdbc

I am trying to insert to my table, a date in format "yyyy-mm-dd". My table has a field `date` type DATETIME and I use SQLite DB SYSTEM. I need to be in this format, so later to have the option to select dates from - then.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE "IsSELECTED"(
           "date" DATETIME PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE) ,
           "morning" BOOL NOT NULL  DEFAULT (0) ,
           "noon" BOOL NOT NULL  DEFAULT (0) ,
           "night" BOOL NOT NULL  DEFAULT (0) 
     )
```

and the method which i am trying to insert.

```
        public void setTodayInfo(HttpSession session, Date date) 
            throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Initialize today's info...");
        String sq = "INSERT INTO IsSELECTED (date, morning, noon, night) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try {       
            Class.forName(typeDB);
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(path);            
            stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);

            PreparedStatement stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);

            stm.setDate(1, date);
            stm.setBoolean(2, FALSE);
            stm.setBoolean(3, FALSE);
            stm.setBoolean(4, FALSE);

            int rowsAffected = stm.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) { 
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
        if (stm != null) {
            stm.close();
        }
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
    }          
    }
```

How can i create a variable (DATE) with the format "yyyy-mm-dd" ?

Comment: A column of the type date has no format.

Comment: Just remember, `Date` has not concept of format in of it self.  The short answer, in your case is, don't.  Let the database driver convert the value from `java.sql.Date` to what ever format the database is expecting.  Then when you select the data from the database, the database driver will convert from the database representation back to `java.sql.Date`

Comment: can you give an example of this, because what I have tried isn't working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the format of the date **when storing it**. The database will simply store the date instance and you can use one of its functions to format it **on retrieval**.

SQL Lite date functions: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

If you don't want to be tied to the functions of a particular database vendor, you could also use Java to format the date on retrieval using SimpleDateFormat: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `DateFormat` instance and work with it. Use `format` to get the String from a Date. Use `parse` to get the Date from the String.
Note that probably you need the format `yyyy-MM-dd` and not `yyyy-mm-dd`. MM means months, mm means minuts

```
Date now = new Date();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(df.format(now)); // Prints today date in yyyy-MM-dd format
Date firstJune = df.parse("2015-06-01");
```

In the database the field is a Date field so you have to save the data converting `String` to `Date` or directly savings a `Date`.

**Note** the format is applied to the `String` representation of your `Date`

Comment: I have this `String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());`

which returns the current date in format 2016-06-17. Now how to insert it the table? the `setDate` needs `Date` format right?

Comment: If you like to save the current date to the db use the following: java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date());  ps.setDate(sqlDate); where ps is a PreparedStatement. Is not necessary to retrieve the string format of the current Date. Use the parse method of DateFormat only if the date is passed manually by the user (from a prompt, from a GUI...)

Comment: Netbeans says that 'incompatible types: Date cannot be converted to long'